# How to get Tex markup associated with rendered Math in MathJax?

Tags: html, mathjax

I have a demo in which I am rendering Math in web page using MathJax.js. This demo is at [Online Demo](http://js.do/sun21170/150745).

I get the Math rendered perfectly, but now I want to do the reverse of Math rendering i.e. get the html markup associated with rendered Math. I tried a couple of methods `MathJax.Hub.getJaxFor(div)` and also `div.innerHTML` but none gave me the original markup.

I want to get the original markup , which in this demo is  `$$x^2 = x +2$$` using some API in MathJax.

**Question**

What API in MathJax will I use to get the original markup in the demo below?

**Demo code**

```
<script>
   function getMathMarkup() {
   var div = document.getElementById("mathMarkup");
   //I need to get the original Tex markup with $$ delimiters
   //once the Math gets rendered
       alert(MathJax.Hub.getJaxFor(div));
       alert(div.innerHTML);
   }
</script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="getMathMarkup();return false;">Get Math Markup</button>
<div id="mathMarkup">
   $$x^2 = x +2$$
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the original markup , which in this demo is  $$x^2 = x +2$$ using some API in MathJax.

That's not possible as such; the delimiters will be removed during pre-processing and are not stored. You would have to track user input yourself if you needed the original.

However, you can look up the display style and derive the delimiters from there.

Here's an example.

```html
<script>
   function getMathMarkup() {
   var div = document.getElementById("mathMarkup");
   //I need to get the original Tex markup with $$ delimiters
   //once the Math gets rendered
   var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("MathMarkup")[0];
   var text =  '$' + math.originalText + '$';
   if (math.root.display) text = '$' + text + '$';
   alert(text);
   };
</script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="getMathMarkup();return false;">Get Math Markup</button>
<div id="mathMarkup">
   $$x^2 = x+2$$
</div>
```

An alternative is to simply look up the script tag that is placed in the DOM right after the output. Then you can reconstruct the information from there, without relying on MathJax's API.

Comment: Thanks. What does `math.root.display` check? Is it related to MathML?

Comment: It checks the input's display style, either block or inline. It is a common difference in math rendering engines. In MathJax's case it is somewhat related to MathML as that is its internal data structure.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I guess there is no easy way to get the input for Math rendering.

Comment: Fast foward to 2024 or version 3.2.2: MathJax.Hub is missing